# How to resolve floating point precision issue in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to find a `explode_percent` column by dividing a column to sum of the bucket.

Below is my query -

```
    SELECT 
        amount,
        sum(amount) over (
            partition by col1,
            col2,
            col3,
            col4
            order by col2,
                col3,
                col4
        ) as explode_amount,
        COALESCE(
            amount / NULLIF(
                SUM(amount) over(
                    partition by col1,
                    col2,
                    col3
                    order by col2,
                        col3,
                        col4
                ),
                0
            ),
            0
        ) as explode_percent
    FROM my_table
```

However this is giving me different values in each run. I've tried casting both numerator and denominator to `decimal(38,7)`, `decimal(38,15)`, `double`, `round` till 7 decimal places but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: Please share sample data and output so we can try to repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs.

There was some issue with the input data itself and apparently the floating point was not giving correct results. Resolved now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using floating-point data types like `double`, consider using the `decimal` data type, which allows you to specify a fixed precision and scale also you can `round` both the numerator and the denominator to a specific number of decimal places before performing the division. Rounding can help in cases where the floating-point representation introduces small errors.

```
WITH normalized_data AS (
    SELECT 
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        amount,
        SUM(amount) OVER (
            PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3
            ORDER BY col2, col3, col4
        ) AS total_amount
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    amount,
    total_amount,
    COALESCE(
        ROUND(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(38, 10)) / NULLIF(CAST(total_amount AS DECIMAL(38, 10)), 0), 7),
        0
    ) AS explode_percent
FROM normalized_data;
```